# Xcode Disable Colon-aligning Auto-indent

Tags: xcode, auto-indent

Is there any way to disable the auto-indent Xcode performs to align colons when breaking up a long method name into multiple lines?

That is, I'd rather not have this:

```
UIBarButtonItem *longDescriptiveButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title of Button"
                                                                          style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                                                         target:self
                                                                         action:@selector(longDescriptiveButtonClicked)];
```

which, as you can see, looks terrible when variable/method/class names are long.

Comment: ...which they almost always are. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Not completely the answer you are looking for, but I'm using uncrustify to do code formatting. I run it from the Xcode scripts menu via a hot key.